# Android - Compare two dates

Tags: android, date

I want to compare two dates in my application

The first date will be todays date
The second will come from a database

To save the second date my code is as follows; (Used tomorrows date to keep it simple)

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
 Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

 String tomorrowAsString = dateFormat.format(tomorrow);
```

So `tomorrowAsString (10-Oct-2015)` is stored in a table in my database

In another form I'm retrieving that date and putting it into a String

```
String steepingDate = (c.getString(3));
```

I imagine that I'll need to convert that string into a date format and then use the following to get todays date;

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = calendar.getTime();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

String todayAsString = dateFormat.format(today);
```

Here is where I'm getting stuck as I'm not sure how to turn the `steepingDate` into a `Date` and then what is the actual way of comparing the strings, I've tried looking online but there's so many different ways that I've tried and none so far have worked. I want to know which one of the two is grater

EDIT:

I've combined some of the answers and come up with the following;

```
do {
      String steepingDate = (c.getString(3));
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
      Date steepingdate = formatter.parse(steepingDate);

      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      Date today = calendar.getTime();

      if(today.compareTo(steepingdate)>0)
      {
         CompleteSteeping.add(c.getString(1));
      }
      i += 1;
   }while (c.moveToNext());
```

However on;

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date steepingdate = formatter.parse(steepingDate);
```

I'm getting an error stating

'Unparseable date: "java.util.GregorianCalender[time=1444461352665,areFieldsSet=true,Ienient=true\zone=GMT,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=41,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=10,DAY_OF_YEAR=283,DAY_OF_WEEK=7,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=7,MINUTE=15,SECOND=52,MILLISECOND=665,ZONE_OFFSET=0DST_OFFSET=0]" (at offset 0)

Comment: Compare in what way? Two dates are not equal or which date comes first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to compare the Strings it would look like this:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    String tomorrowAsString = dateFormat.format(tomorrow);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date today = calendar.getTime();

    String todayAsString = dateFormat.format(today);

    if(tomorrowAsString.equals(todayAsString))
        System.out.println(true);
    else
        System.out.println(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have been more clear in my question it's not just knowing if they are equal or not it's knowing which one is grater

Comment: So then should the answer from Amit Desale work for you. ;)

Comment: I've updated my question as getting an error on what I've tried

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
It just can´t handle dd-MM-yyyy.

Comment: Your right, I changed the original format when the data is being stored to database from dd-MMM-yyyy to dd/MMM/yyyy and it's now working

Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 1):

> Here is where I'm getting stuck as I'm not sure how to turn the
>   steepingDate into a Date

You need to instantiate  a `SimpleDateFormat` with a patter that matches the String you saved, and call `parse` on it.

> and then what is the actual way of comparing the strings, I've tried
>   looking online but there's so many different ways that I've tried and
>   none so far have worked

if you have to compare date to understand if one is less/grater/equal than, then Date has the [compareTo](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) method, which returns an int < 0 if this Date is less than the specified Date, 0 if they are equal, and an int > 0 if this Date is greater.

Comment: I've updated my question as getting an error on what I've tried

Comment: It's in the question
`tomorrowAsString (10-Oct-2015)` but it's the string is called steepingDate
However I've just noticed that I had dd/MM/yyyy so I've now changed it to dd-MM-yyyy but still getting an error

Comment: are you getting the same error ? Could you update the question posting the changes you made and post the stacktrace of the exception ?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from `String` date to `Date` and compare it

Use the SimpleDateFormat class:

```
private Date parseDate(String date, String format) throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return formatter.parse(date);
}
Usage:

Date date = parseDate("19/05/2009", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: I've updated my question as getting an error on what I've tried